# Reduce data traffic in JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am exposing a couple domain objects via a SOAP based web service. Some of my domain objects have a large number of fields. I do not want to include values in my web service request/response unless they are needed.

For example, if I have a Book domain object with fields title, genre, and isbn, if I wanted to use my web service to update the name of a book, I want my request to only include the title field (omitting the other two fields that aren't being updated).

Likewise, I want my web service clients to be able to specify which fields they want to be returned when they load books.

This would allow clients to load the title field thereby reducing the size of the data going across the wire because the fields that aren't needed would not be included in the response.

Does anyone know of any patterns or best practices to deal with this type of requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You touched multiple problems where each deserves separate explanation:

- Reducing traffic - reducing traffic usually means reducing roundtrips not reducing payload. Reducing traffic is achieved by implement better operations which do multiple actions instead of exposing CRUD operations.
- Reducing payload - if you don't want to transfer whole entity you should use Data transfer objects. Special object transferring only data required for given operation.
- Dynamic response - web services are not supposed to do that. Web service has fixed interface defined by WSDL where each message payload is specified by XSD. If you want dynamically change returned data structure you will break this. It doesn't mean it is not possible - you can define that your service operation returns xsd:any = any XML and it will be your duty to prepare returned XML and duty of your client to parse XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the fields *optional* in the XSD data type, or you can specify that in the `changeTitle` request you don't expect a `Book`, but only an ID and a string.

When you invent the `changeAttributes` request and you have optional fields, you have to decide what a missing field means. It could be *clear this field* or *leave this field untouched*.